# "IndexError: list index out of range" when performing string checking

Tags: python, string, validation, comparison

Ideally, I'd like to be able to prompt users for "Small" or "S", "Medium" or "M" and "Large" or "L" when determining prices for drinks. This is all case insensitive, so "s" or "smaLL" is good, etc. If i input just an 'M', I get an error for an index code out of range, and it computes as a small. A large gives me a medium. Help?

```
print("Ie. 'S', 'M', 'L', 'Small', 'Medium, 'Large'" +
      " or any variations in their letter case sensitivity will work.")
beverageSize = str(input("Input your desired size: "))
print("")

if len(beverageSize) > 1 and len(beverageSize) < 5:
  exit(print("Error with choice of beverage input."))

elif beverageSize.startswith("S") or beverageSize.startswith("s") and\
            beverageSize is beverageSize.isalpha() and len(beverageSize) == 0 or len(beverageSize) == 4 or\
            beverageSize[0] == "S" or beverageSize[0] == "s" and\
            beverageSize[1] == "M" or beverageSize[1] == "m" or beverageSize[1] == "" and\
            beverageSize[2] == "A" or beverageSize[2] == "a" or beverageSize[2] == "" and\
            beverageSize[3] == "L" or beverageSize[3] == "l" or beverageSize[3] == "" and\
            beverageSize[4] == "L" or beverageSize[4] == "l" or beverageSize[4] == "" and\
           len(beverageSize) != 5:

        beverageSize = SMALL_SIZE
        print("SMALl")


elif beverageSize.startswith("M") or beverageSize.startswith("m") and\
            beverageSize is beverageSize.isalpha() and\     len(beverageSize) == 0 or len(beverageSize) == 5 or \
            beverageSize[0] == "M" or beverageSize[0] == "m" and\
            beverageSize[1] == "E" or beverageSize[1] == "e" or beverageSize[1] == "" and\
            beverageSize[2] == "D" or beverageSize[3] == "d" or beverageSize[3] == "" and\
            beverageSize[3] == "I" or beverageSize[3] == "i" or beverageSize[3] == "" and\
            beverageSize[4] == "U" or beverageSize[4] == "u" or beverageSize[4] == "" and\
            beverageSize[5] == "M" or beverageSize[5] == "m" or beverageSize[5] == "":

        beverageSize = MEDIUM_SIZE
        print("MEDIUM")
```

Comment: Please just use `if beverageSize.lower() == 'medium'`.

Comment: you really made things way too complicated. Use `beverageSize.lower() in {`'s', 'small'}` to test if `s` or `small` was typed in, in any case combination.

Comment: but I'm trying to make the prompt be case insensitive, so Medium, MEdium, MEdiUM and any other combination I wish. .lowercase() would just give me all lowercase would it not?

Comment: But that's the whole point. You convert the user input to all lowercase and then you just need to test it against your all lowercase target words.

Comment: @D.Kyle By converting your input to lowercase, you need just test it against ONE value. Isn't that easier than what you are doing?

Answer (score 2):

There are smarter ways for testing the value of variables in python. One method using `if-else` conditions has already been [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512839/keep-getting-index-out-of-range-error-when-using-if-else-statements-on-python/46512890#comment79979848_46512839) in the comments. Here's another short, concise method using a `dict`:

```
size_dict = {'s' : SMALL_SIZE, 'small' : SMALL_SIZE, 
             'm' : MEDIUM_SIZE,'medium' : MEDIUM_SIZE,
             'l' : LARGE_SIZE, 'large' : LARGE_SIZE}
beverageSize = size_dict.get(beverageSize.lower(), 'Invalid Size')
```

This uses `dict.get` to extract values associated with your input. If the user entered a word that does not exist as a key in the dictionary, then `beverageSize` is assigned the value `Invalid Size`.

Comment: This is not a good solution, as 'lol' will also be interpreted as 'large'. This is not good practice.

Comment: @DanielTrugman The assumption is that anything starting with l is taken to be large, even if "lol" is the input. I don't think there's anything wrong with it, if at all, it's more flexible than an if-else.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Doing correct input validation is the #1 rule of user interaction, whether it's Python, C, or a REST API. Please don't encourage such implementations.

Comment: @PM2Ring Okay. It should be fine now.

Comment: @DanielTrugman There's no need to make a big deal out of it, the fix was only adding a couple of keys - if that was so important OP could've done it themselves. The point I was trying to make was that this is still more concise than a cascade of ifs, which it is. You're preaching to the choir.

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all, your program won't work because this will always be true for allowed values:

```
if len(beverageSize) > 1 and len(beverageSize) < 5:
  exit(print("Error with choice of beverage input."))
```

Then, give yourself a break and avoid all lower/uppercase checks by just using this before comparing stuff:

```
bevarageSize = bevarageSize.lower()
```

Now start comparing:

```
if (beverageSize == 's' or bevarageSize == 'small'):
  print 'small'
elif (beverageSize == 'm' or bevarageSize == 'medium'):
  print 'medium'
elif (beverageSize == 'l' or bevarageSize == 'large'):
  print 'large'
```

Or even better, using real Python style:

```
if (beverageSize in ('s', 'small')):
  print 'small'
elif (beverageSize in ('m', 'medium')):
  print 'medium'
elif (beverageSize in ('l', 'large')):
  print 'large'
```

Comment: This isn't python, though.

Comment: Coldspeed, you are right, I tried to avoid confusing this fella and ended up with ugly python code... Added a clear implementation, as intended.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm writing C++ as we speak and things got mixed up :(